# unable to run arcgis getting started scripts in vue app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, arcgis

I'm trying to include some start up script for an arc gis map but it requires the script tag I have inside my mounted() prop function to run first. Does anyone know what hook I can use to run this code after the script has been properly required? trying to run the code on start is giving me an error that it's missing the dependencies from the script.

My assumption the script is running before any dependencies load

I have the following app setup

```
<script>
import { loadModules } from 'esri-loader';
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data(){
      return{
        nodes:[],
        addingNodes: false,
        xClick: null,
        yClick: null,
      }
  },
  mounted() {

    loadModules([
            "esri/Map",
            "esri/views/MapView"
        ], { css: true })
        .then(([Map,MapView]) => {
             var map = new Map({
                 basemap: "streets"
             });
             var view = new MapView({
                 container: "map",
                 map: map,
                 zoom: 4,
                 center: [15, 65]
             });
        });


    },
  methods:{
      drawArea(){
        console.log('drawing area')
        if(this.nodes.length > 2){
          console.log('drawing shape')
        }else{
           alert(`you only have ${this.nodes.length} nodes, you need at least 3 to draw a polygon`)
        }
      },
      addNodes(){
        if(this.addingNodes === true){
        console.log('adding nodes')

        let point = {
          x: this.xClick,
          y: this.yClick
        }

        this.nodes = [...this.nodes, point] //add point to the nodes Array
        }
      },
  },

}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

  #viewDiv {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0 auto;
      height: 80%;
      width: 80%;
    }

</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use "esri-loader" in your vue app

```
npm install "esri-loader"
```

then, in your Vue-Single-Page file

```
<template>
    <div id="map"></div>
</template>
<style scoped>
    #map{
        width:100%;
        height:300px;
    }
</style>
<script>
import { loadModules } from 'esri-loader';
export default{
    mounted(){

        // lazy load modules
        loadModules([
            'esri/layers/WebTileLayer',
            'esri/Map',
            'esri/views/SceneView',
        ], { css: true })
        .then(([WebTileLayer,Map,SceneView]) => {

            let map = new Map();

            // use Google Map Web tile
            let tiled_layer = new WebTileLayer({
                urlTemplate: 'http://www.google.cn/maps/vt/pb=!1m4!1m3!1i{level}!2i{col}!3i{row}!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i345013117!3m8!2szh-CN!3scn!5e1105!12m4!1e68!2m2!1sset!2sRoadmap!4e0',
            });
            map.add(tiled_layer);

            let map_view = new SceneView({
                map:map,
                container:"map",          
                scale:110329633.40563367, 
                center:[105.578034,34.062071]
            });

        });
    }
}
</script>
```

---

here is a simplest example for 2D map

```
<template>
    <div id="map" style="height:300px;width:300px;"></div>
</template>
<script>
import { loadModules } from 'esri-loader';
export default{
    mounted(){
        loadModules([
            "esri/Map",
            "esri/views/MapView"
        ], { css: true })
        .then(([Map,MapView]) => {
             let map = new Map({
                 basemap: "streets"
             });
             let view = new MapView({
                 container: "map",
                 map: map,
                 zoom: 4,
                 center: [15, 65]
             });
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: that's great, I didn't know there was such a package, unfortunately after trying this I get an error:   error  'map_view' is assigned a value but never used. I have updated my div's id to 'map'. I also checked out the npm docs and I get the same error trying to render this as the 2d version map instead of the 3d version.

Comment: @monsterpiece If you want to create a 2D map, you don't need to use `SceneView` class, use `MapView` instead of it.

Comment: @monsterpiece I just edit the answer for adding a 2D map example which from [official example](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/intro-mapview/index.html)

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I seem to keep getting the error that view is declared but not used? I know there's not any other steps in arcgis that I need to do in order to set up the map and this code works in a lone html page. I am using a vue app.js then importing it into my html, i don't know if that has anything to do with why it won't work?

Comment: @monsterpiece How do you use vue.js in your app? By npm or by cdn? Could you show me your app.js and the output in your console? For me, when I create a new vue project with arcgis, there is always only one javascript file in my html which named `app.js`, the others are imported dynamically. According to what you said about the error happened to you. I guess it probably is not the error from arcgis, it's an error from your `app.js`.

Comment: I agree, it has to be an app.js error, I have used vue cli to create the initial application and my app.vue is my only file, however it is inside my src folder and my index.html is inside my public folder. I thought that including the map inside my app before pushing it to the DOM would work fine. I was hoping to use vue cli for easy access to the webpack dev server.

Comment: @monsterpiece Have you fix the error? If the error still there , maybe you can try to use `window.map = new Map({...}); window.view = new MapView({...});` install of `let`. Make the variables be global not local

Comment: unfortunately no I haven't been able to fix the error yet, setting the variables to global hasn't had any effect. I'm currently trying to find a way to avoid using webpack altogether and have included my vue inside a static html page. All I really need to be able to do is make sure the map can receive vue variables.

Comment: after looking through some documentation I found that I also needed to include the Map and view directly in my app.vue like so    import ArcGISMap from 'esri/Map';
import MapView from 'esri/views/MapView';

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below. This will wait until mapScript has finished loading before calling the dependent code.

```
mounted() {
  let mapScript = document.createElement('script')
  mapScript.setAttribute('src', 'https://js.arcgis.com/4.15/')
  document.head.appendChild(mapScript);
  mapScript.addEventListener('load', () => {
      //run your code that is dependent on https://js.arcgis.com/4.15/
  });
}
```